# Classis ASP debugging global.asa in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005, asp-classic, global.asa

I was trying to set a breakpoint in global.asa in an old classic ASP project with IIS 6 in Visual Studio 2005.

Somehow the context menu for actually setting the breakpoint somewhere in global.asa is disabled (greyed). How can I set a breakpoint then?

Breakpoints in .asp pages are no problem though and do work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [How to: Debug Global.asa files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241868(VS.80).aspx). The short version is to place a VBScript Stop statement or JScript debugger at the beginning of the procedure, before any statements that you will want to step through.